# Adding Tags to Blog's Index Page on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-tags

I'm trying to edit this [Tumblr theme](http://pastebin.com/1mEqBCnt). It doesn't show tags on the index page, but shows them on permalink pages. I've put

```
{block:HasTags}
{block:Tags}
<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
{/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
```

everywhere I could think of within `{block:Posts}`, including `{block:indexpage}` and the individual post type blocks. If I put the code in the index page block, the tags end up behind the next post and the accent border disappears if they are long enough. If I put it in the post type blocks, I can't format them.

Ideally, I want to put the tags after the info like the notes and date on the index page, but I'm not sure of how to do that.